# How to check that only one value in an array is non-zero?

Tags: ruby

Given an array like : `[0,1,1]`

How can I elegantly check that: *Only one element has a non-zero value and that the others are 0?*

(So the above array will fail the check while this array will pass : `[1,0,0]`)

Comment: How big will this array be?  Sometime elegant is overkill if an array will only have a (relatively) few elements.

Comment: It will be tiny, maybe 4-5 elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my_array.count(0) == my_array.length-1
```

If speed is important, for very large arrays where you might need to return early upon detecting a second non-zero, perhaps:

```
def only_one_non_zero?( array )
  found_non_zero = false
  array.each do |val|
    if val!=0
      return false if found_non_zero
      found_non_zero = true
    end
  end
  found_non_zero
end
```

Comment: @Phrogz Where does the `count` method come from? I don't see it in the `Array` class nor in `Enumerable`.

Comment: Great way to do it. @Jacob - The `count` method only exists from Ruby 1.8.7 and beyond. See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html

Comment: @JacobRelkin It's in my Array: `Array.instance_methods(false).grep /count/ #=> [:count]`. It's certainly [present in 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000753).

Comment: @Phrogz @dotangg Makes sense, I was looking at the `core` reference.

Comment: `break unless found_non_zero ^= true if val != 0`

Answer (score 6):

Select at most two non-zero elements, and check if exactly one item was available.

```
>> [0,1,1].select {|x| !x.zero?}.take(2).size == 1
=> false
>> [0,1,0].select {|x| !x.zero?}.take(2).size == 1
=> true
>> [1,2,3].select {|x| !x.zero?}.take(2).size == 1
=> false
```

Works fine in Ruby 1.8.7, but note that `select` returns an array, so it's not "optimally lazy".  [Here's a blog post](http://www.michaelharrison.ws/weblog/?p=163) showing how to make some lazy enumerators in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your answers!

I solved too:

```
input_array = [0,0,0]
result = input_array - [0]
p result.size == 1 && result[0] == 1
```

Ruby, I love you!

Comment: You can simplify that further: `[0,0,0] - [0] #=> []` which means you could write: `result = input_array - [0]`